# Why does the texture from my mesh override the other that's separately textured in render mode - cycles

Tags: texturing

[image]

the skin is textured and the eye is textured, how come when I move the eye on to the head the texture from the skin is overriding the eye.[image]

[image]
went into cycles mode rendered and I noticed the face overlays the iris of the eyeball.

How would I move this without deleting anything.

also is there a way to make the eyeball overlay and stand in front of the eye.

edit:
with me also thinking this was just a problem that needed to be spotted out with that particular mesh, it's also going on with my new one.
[image]

also I noticed this going on inside of my mesh that the eye could probably be reflecting light through the head making it visible on the skin.
[image]

Comment: Hi :). This looks a bit like overlapping geometry. Have you checked that?

Comment: Hey, merged all of the vertices by distance and when rendered same result. I wish this was the answer but thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because the eye globe is transparent, it lets see the iris, and the iris crosses the mesh of the head:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I could make the eye globe non transparent? also thanks !!

Comment: sure but you won't see the iris anymore   ;)

Comment: ok, as long as it shows in render mode, or maybe you have a better alternative.

Comment: I have to say, I have no easy solution for your problem, you should probably dig a hole for the eyes (or enlarge the current hole so that the mesh doesn't interact with the eye ball